# Primitive element of the fixed field of a subgroup of the galois group of a prime cyclotomic extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials

This is a question on one step in a proof from Dummit and Foote pg. 597.

Let $p$ be an odd prime (there isn't much to say for the $p=2$ case) and let $G=\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q(\zeta_p)}/\mathbb{Q})$ where $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity.  Let $H\leq G$.  Define $\alpha:=\sum_{\sigma\in H} \sigma(\zeta_p)$.  The claim is that the fixed field of $H$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ e.g. $\text{Fix } H=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

We first show that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subseteq \text{Fix }H$.

The other direction: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\supseteq \text{Fix }H\Longleftrightarrow G(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))\subseteq H$ which by contrapositive is equivalent to $\sigma\not\in H\Longrightarrow \sigma\not\in G(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))$  Now, every $\sigma\in G$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ so to show this last implication it is sufficient to check that $\sigma\not\in H$ implies that $\sigma$ does NOT fix $\alpha$.

> Dummit and Foote says to next let $\tau\not\in H$.  Then if we had $\tau(\alpha)=\alpha$ we get $\tau(\zeta_p)=\sigma(\zeta_p)$ for some $\sigma\in H$.  From here I can complete the problem.

I know that $\{\zeta_p^k\}_0^{p-2}$ and $\{\zeta_p^k\}_1^{p-1}$ are both bases for $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.  I also know that automorphisms permute the set $\{\zeta_p^k\}_1^{p-1}$.

Might be useful to write (say) $(1,0,1,1,1,0)$ as $\alpha$ in $\{\zeta_p^k\}_1^{p-1}$-coordinates and say that any automorphism that fixes that element must "fix" the coordinates in that only powers with like coefficients are exchanged.  (Else, we would have two different solutions which is impossible because we have a basis)

The question is, how *exactly* does the statement in the blockquote work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the primitive roots of unity form a basis, if an automorphism fixes the sum of a certain subset of them, then by the uniqueness of an element as a linear combination of the basis, that automorphism must just permute those roots of unity, meaning it sends $\zeta_p$ to some $\sigma(\zeta_p)$.

Comment: Do you mean to say that if (say) $p=5$ and $f$ an automorphism fixing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(\zeta^2+\zeta^3)=\zeta^2+\zeta^3$ then $f(\zeta^2)\in\{\zeta^2,\zeta^3\}$?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are saying: Starting with $\alpha=\tau(\alpha)=\sigma(\alpha)$ (true for all $\sigma\in H$) we know that $\tau(\zeta)=\zeta^i$ for some $i$.  Let $x$ be the coefficient of $\zeta^i$ in the basis representation of $\alpha$.  Then by the uniqueness of such representations, $x\zeta^i$ must appear in the representation of $\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(\zeta)$ but that sum is already a representation since each $\sigma$ is distinct so must necessarily send $\zeta$ to the different powers.

Comment: Yes (to your first comment). Primitive roots are send to primitive roots, and they form a basis, so they can only permute what's already there.

Comment: But now the problem is, if $\tau(\zeta)=\zeta^i$ then its still possible that the coefficient of $\zeta$ in the representation for $\alpha$ to be zero.  In which case the coefficient of $\zeta^i$ in the rep for $\alpha$ is also zero.  So we never get $\sigma(\zeta)=\tau(\zeta)$ because $\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(\zeta)$ is a representation.

Comment: Maybe better to say:  $\alpha=\sum_1^{p-1}a_i\tau(\zeta)^i=\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(\zeta)$ (LHS=basis representation) so for some $i$ $\tau(\zeta^i)=\sigma(\zeta)$, but not necessarily $i=1$ as needed.

Comment: Since $H$ contains the identity automorphism, one of the summands of $\alpha$ is $id(\zeta_p)=\zeta_p$.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  From what I can tell, you need $\zeta$ to actually appear in the basis rep. for $\alpha$.  Otherwise since $\zeta$ doesn't appear as a $\sigma_i(\zeta)$ any automorphism in fact cannot send $\zeta$ to a $\sigma_i(\zeta)$.  (From uniqueness of basis representations)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^i$ for some $i$. Thus the equation $\tau(\zeta)=\sigma(\zeta)$ is actually a polynomial in $\zeta$. Now it is easy to see that unless the polynomial equality is an identity (the same terms in different order)  we get a contradiction to the irreduciblity of the equation for $\zeta$.

Comment: My problem is how to prove that $\tau(\zeta)=\sigma(\zeta)$ (for some $\sigma$ in $H$) in the first place.  Unless you meant to write "$\tau(\alpha)=\sigma(\alpha)$ is a polynomial in $\zeta$" which is true since both functions are automorphisms and so permute $\{\zeta,\ldots,\zeta^{p-1}\}$.  Though I am still not sure how to proceed.